# No Module error from minidump_stackwalk in Breakpad

Tags: c++, linux, google-breakpad, crashpad

I have started working with google breakpad on Linux very recently. I have cloned it and built it successfully. I followed the steps given in: https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master/docs/linux_starter_guide.md. I have created my minidump file and symbol file successfully but when I run minidump_stalkwalk I get this:

```
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5089: INFO: Minidump opened minidump /home/bhararit/a.dmp
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5219: INFO: Minidump not byte-swapping minidump
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5871: INFO: GetStream: type 15 not present
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5871: INFO: GetStream: type 1197932545 not present
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5871: INFO: GetStream: type 1197932546 not present
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /home/bhararit/a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for linux-gate.so
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /home/bhararit/a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for linux-gate.so
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5871: INFO: GetStream: type 14 not present
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump_processor.cc:174: INFO: Found 2 memory regions.
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump_processor.cc:184: INFO: Minidump /home/bhararit/a.dmp has CPU info, OS info, no Breakpad info, exception, module list, thread list, no dump thread, requesting thread, and no process create time
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump_processor.cc:223: INFO: Looking at thread /home/bhararit/a.dmp:0/1 id 0x15ec
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:474: INFO: MinidumpContext: looks like AMD64 context
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:474: INFO: MinidumpContext: looks like AMD64 context
2021-05-04 13:26:23: simple_symbol_supplier.cc:196: INFO: No symbol file at /home/bhararit/breakpad/src/tools/linux/dump_syms/symbols/test/732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30//a/732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30/a.sym
2021-05-04 13:26:23: stackwalker.cc:103: INFO: Couldn't load symbols for: /home/bhararit/a|732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffff00000000
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9efa7
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x2d
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9efc7
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xfffffffffffffffe
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7fd749b5ffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: simple_symbol_supplier.cc:196: INFO: No symbol file at /home/bhararit/breakpad/src/tools/linux/dump_syms/symbols/test/732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30//libc.so.6/25929B09B0BC19D0D9D60884BE583EB30/libc.so.6.sym
2021-05-04 13:26:23: stackwalker.cc:103: INFO: Couldn't load symbols for: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6|25929B09B0BC19D0D9D60884BE583EB30
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffff00000000
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f057
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x2d
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x55f21deb0edf
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x29
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x4b
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x28f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x55f21deb0edf
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xfffffffffffffffe
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x400000002
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f0d7
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f0d7
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f0ef
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f0ef
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x39f6f4120d44edff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f20f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7fd749b6ab7f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f217
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x100011bff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x419c5360235cbe33
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f20f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xbe61a633c13cbe33
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xbe32c054e392be33
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f217
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f227
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7fd749dd118f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f20f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaa9f207
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x1b
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x0
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1446
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0xffffffffffffffff
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa144a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa145a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa14c6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa14d9
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa14ed
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa151a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1531
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa155d
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa156f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa158f
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa15b8
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa15cc
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa15e3
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa15f6
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1612
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1625
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1636
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1651
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1666
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa169a
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa16c3
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa16e4
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa16f1
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1705
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1717
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1729
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1734
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1d16
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1d37
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1d48
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1d9e
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1dcd
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1ddd
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1df5
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1e17
2021-05-04 13:26:23: basic_code_modules.cc:111: INFO: No module at 0x7ffefaaa1e2e
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump_processor.cc:348: INFO: Processed /home/bhararit/a.dmp
Operating system: Linux
                  0.0.0 Linux 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 142 stepping 10
     4 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  SIGFPE / FPE_INTDIV
Crash address: 0x55f21c023f6d
Process uptime: not available

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  a + 0x2f6d
    rax = 0x0000000000000001   rdx = 0x0000000000000000
    rcx = 0x000055f21deb4f80   rbx = 0x000055f21c036340
    rsi = 0x0000000000000000   rdi = 0x000055f21c03e6c0
    rbp = 0x00007ffefaa9f120   rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9ef80
     r8 = 0x0000000000000000    r9 = 0x000055f21deb4f78
    r10 = 0x0000000000000008   r11 = 0x00007fd749b6abe0
    r12 = 0x000055f21c023d70   r13 = 0x00007ffefaa9f210
    r14 = 0x0000000000000000   r15 = 0x0000000000000000
    rip = 0x000055f21c023f6d
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  libc.so.6 + 0x9a9fb
    rbp = 0x00007ffefaa9f120   rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f020
    rip = 0x00007fd749a199fb
    Found by: stack scanning
 2  a + 0x2e59
    rbp = 0x00007ffefaa9f120   rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f030
    rip = 0x000055f21c023e59
    Found by: stack scanning
 3  a + 0x15340
    rbp = 0x00007ffefaa9f120   rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f120
    rip = 0x000055f21c036340
    Found by: stack scanning
 4  libc.so.6 + 0x270b3
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f130   rip = 0x00007fd7499a60b3
    Found by: stack scanning
 5  a + 0x2e98
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f150   rip = 0x000055f21c023e98
    Found by: stack scanning
 6  a + 0x15340
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f158   rip = 0x000055f21c036340
    Found by: stack scanning
 7  a + 0x2d70
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f168   rip = 0x000055f21c023d70
    Found by: stack scanning
 8  a + 0x2d70
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f1e0   rip = 0x000055f21c023d70
    Found by: stack scanning
 9  a + 0x2d9e
    rsp = 0x00007ffefaa9f200   rip = 0x000055f21c023d9e
    Found by: stack scanning

Loaded modules:
0x55f21c021000 - 0x55f21c036fff  a  ???  (main)  (WARNING: No symbols, a, 732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30)
0x7fd749830000 - 0x7fd7498e5fff  libm.so.6  ???
0x7fd74997f000 - 0x7fd749b1bfff  libc.so.6  ???  (WARNING: No symbols, libc.so.6, 25929B09B0BC19D0D9D60884BE583EB30)
0x7fd749b71000 - 0x7fd749b85fff  libgcc_s.so.1  ???
0x7fd749b8c000 - 0x7fd749d11fff  libstdc++.so.6  ???
0x7fd749d6d000 - 0x7fd749d84fff  libpthread.so.0  ???
0x7fd749da2000 - 0x7fd749dc5fff  ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  ???
0x7ffefabd0000 - 0x7ffefabd1fff  linux-gate.so  ???
2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:5061: INFO: Minidump closing minidump
```

Any idea how I can correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> 2021-05-04 13:26:23: minidump.cc:2255: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for /home/bhararit/a

It seems that you build an excutable file `a`, then you shoud put `a.sym` into  `symbols/a/732B50B9AE7624466123C019CE134BB30/a.sym`, not `symbols/test/...`

---

Checkout my tutorial repos:

- CLI for Linxu/macOS: https://github.com/Sunbreak/cli-breakpad.trial
- Flutter for Android: https://github.com/Sunbreak/flutter-breakpad.trial